# iframe display:none not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <iframe src="http://www.amway.in/Shopping/Products.aspx?pid=101154IDK&ctg=Nutrilite">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </body>

  <style>
    iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {  
      display: none;
    }
iframe {
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
}
  </style>

  <script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $("iframe").contents().find(".left-nav").css("display","none");
});
  </script>

</html>
```

I want to change the css property "display" as "none" but it showing an error after page loading.

- *Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.amway.in".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.*

Comment: You cannot modify the contents of an iframe if you are fetching a page from a different domain

Answer (score 2):

That's because of *Same-origin policy*.

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin.
>   [...]
>
> ### Cross-origin script API access
>
> JavaScript APIs such as `iframe.contentWindow`, `window.parent`, `window.open` and `window.opener` allow documents to directly reference each other. **When the two documents do not have the same origin, these references provide limited access to the Window and Location objects**. Some browsers allow access to more properties than the spec allows. You can use `window.postMessage` instead to communicate between documents.

You can read more about this subject [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).